# spring-data-couchbase throws DocumentDoesNotExistException for non-existent documents

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache, spring-data-couchbase

I am using `spring-data-couchbase 2.1.2` with `spring-boot 1.4.0.RC1` and `couchbase-spring-cache`

It works fine when caching is disabled as it returns NULL object When caching is enabled and try to find a non-existing document in the bucket it throws an exception:

```
com.couchbase.client.java.error.DocumentDoesNotExistException: null
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncBucket$22.call(CouchbaseAsyncBucket.java:684) ~[java-client-2.2.8.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncBucket$22.call(CouchbaseAsyncBucket.java:671) ~[java-client-2.2.8.jar:na]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:234) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.onNext(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:223) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onCompleted(AsyncSubject.java:101) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.completeResponse(AbstractGenericHandler.java:354) ~[core-io-1.2.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.access$000(AbstractGenericHandler.java:72) ~[core-io-1.2.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler$1.call(AbstractGenericHandler.java:372) ~[core-io-1.2.9.jar:na]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.core.message.kv.RemoveResponse.class
    at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:109) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport(Exceptions.java:188) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:56) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Is it because of AsyncBucket? Is it possible to disable AsyncBucket?

Source code https://github.com/maverickmicky/spring-couchbase-cache

Comment: could you share some code? are you sure it happens when loading the document (ie. happens even if only using simple `@Cacheable`)?

Comment: I don't think it is because of `AsyncBucket`, and it cannot be disabled as it is  the foundation for the Couchbase SDK

Comment: added source code, u need to have couchbase running locally with bucket name 'player'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue indeed... As soon as an eviction attempt for a key that isn't in cache is made, the exception will be thrown :(

I've created [an issue](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-spring-cache/issues/11) for this (with work arounds).

edit: To work around the issue, you should be able to declare a `CacheErrorHandler` that has a `handleCacheEvictError` method that simply catches `DocumentDoesNotExistException`.
See the documentation section on configuring the cache abstraction [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotation-enable) and the [`CachingConfigurer` javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachingConfigurer.html).

Comment: in Spring Boot 1.4, a lot of what you did with your `Database` class is redundant and can be autoconfigured. instead you'll just need the proper entries in `application.property` + a `@Configuration` `@EnableCaching` class that extends `CachingConfigurerSupport` and provides the `CacheErrorHandler` implementation.

Comment: Ok. But the issue I face is during the fetching. When i call 'findOne' on the document which is does not exist then it throws the exception.

Any sample for autoconfiguration?

Comment: I saw ur commits in git. I will try the cache handler.
Is it possible to get those properties from environment variables? I am deploying this in docker and couchbase params are configured through entrypoint.sh

Comment: ah I see why: you call an `@Cacheable` annotated method, which updates the cache after getting the data from canonical source. so it ends up doing a `put(null)` and the `CouchbaseCache` will interpret that as an eviction (which may be a bad design decision on my part). You can use `unless = "#result == null"` on `@Cacheable` to work around this one

Comment: to get properties from the environment, refer to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: did another PR for the `getPlayer` triggering the issue

Comment: ok, so if I use 'spring.couchbase.bootstrap-hosts' as the param in my entrypoint it will be available to spring from env variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118460/discussion-between-mickygo-and-simon-basle).

Comment: @SimonBaslé, I am not using caching, but still, I am getting above mentioned error.I am using couchbase 6.0 with springboot webflux.

Answer (score 1):

I am across the same exception and use case is I am caching the resource which return null, for example:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "EMPLOYEE_", key = "#id")
public Employee getEmployee(int id) {
    return null;
}
```

And fixed it using the `unless` attribute of [`@Cacheable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) which is available as of **Spring 3.2**, as follows:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "EMPLOYEE_", key = "#id", unless = "#result == null")
public Employee getEmployee(int id) {
    return null;
}
```

Have written an article as well which describe my problem and fix for the same - [Fixing com.couchbase.client.java.error.DocumentDoesNotExistException – Couchbase](https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/2017/01/30/fixing-com-couchbase-client-java-error-documentdoesnotexistexception-couchbase/)